# OpenCV installation Google Colab

Tags: opencv, google-colaboratory

I am trying to install OpenCV in google colab notebook.
The official documentation says to do:

```
!apt-get -qq install -y libsm6 libxext6 && pip install -q -U opencv-python
import cv2
```

The first statement works fine and installs everything.
But on importing cv2 I am getting an error saying:

```
ImportError: libSM.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Any fix for this issue?
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't reproduce this issue. The snippet above seems to work fine. 
https://colab.research.google.com/notebook#fileId=1OnUy6eFE7XhdfGfAHDCqQxpwueTOj_NO

Perhaps try restarting your backend via the Runtime -> Restart runtime menu.

Comment: Yes it was a problem with the runtime! I restarted it and it works just as fine.Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

OpenCV comes preinstalled on Google colab.

Simply import cv2 and use it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use **Python 3.x.x** version.
it works, I checked it.

Answer (score 0):

Open CV comes preinstalled on Google Colab, so you can run it but if you want to run it in a window then you need to import more Colab opencv modules.ie. **from google.colab import files**